# What is the origin of "dirt simple"?

Tags: phrases

We did some google searches for the origin of "dirt simple" and we can not find it.

I personally learned it from a college roommate who was from India, and I have borrowed it from him for the last 20 years.

Could this be from "dirt cheap?"

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please provide some context and include any research you have done. For example: how is this word used?

Comment: Appears to have been used in the figurative sense since [1969](https://books.google.com/books?id=mp8ZAQAAMAAJ&q=%22dirt+simple%22&dq=%22dirt+simple%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj77fz_mafRAhWogFQKHU5LAiQ4ChDoAQgfMAE).

Comment: From [1985](https://books.google.com/books?id=dhUqAQAAIAAJ&q=%22dirt+simple%22&dq=%22dirt+simple%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeuqHImqfRAhXjlVQKHayECF8Q6AEIIDAB).

Comment: (This isn't a highly-used idiom, but it is one that I hear from time to time, and it's meaning is fairly intuitive -- almost laughably uncomplicated.)